# Enable ssl_module at wampserver

Tags: apache, email, module, wampserver

when i enabled ssl_module, apache always not working
if i disable ssl_module

```
#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

my wampserver will work again.

i try sending mail using gmail via localhost & CodeIgniter, and i got this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
>   messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 2063
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: D:\wamp64\www\TracerStudy\application\controllers\regis.php
>   Line: 128 Function: send
>
> File: D:\wamp64\www\TracerStudy\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

-- Update --
I got this Error:

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

my Code :

```
$config = Array(
          'protocol' => 'smtp',
          'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
          'smtp_port' => 465,
          'smtp_user' => 'mymail', 
          'smtp_pass' => 'mypassword', 
          'mailtype' => 'html',
          'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
          'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl',
          'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );

        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from('myemail');
        $this->email->to('sendemail'); 
        $this->email->subject('subject');
        $this->email->message('message');
        if($this->email->send())
        {
          echo 'Email sent.';
        }
        else
        {
          show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

disable your anti virus... it solved my problem